# Meaning of Trending and Most Viewed

Tags: sharepoint-online

I can’t seem to figure it out  how files are actually classified based on these two options.
I guess the files the are mostly open go under most viewed. What about trending items ?

Does anyone have more information on how data gets categorized based on these two Standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popularity Trending is used to identify at what times activity is high or low, it's more of a time range activity at different levels - Site Collection, Site and Library/List Item. The reports are formed daily or monthly.

Most Viewed is focused on items at List/Library level. You can sort the list by Recent (the last 14 days), or Ever.

References.

[Popularity Trends and Most Popular Items reports in SharePoint 2013.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30861.popularity-trends-and-most-popular-items-reports-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

[View Popularity Trends and Most Popular Items.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-popularity-trends-and-most-popular-items#view-the-most-popular-items-in-a-library)